# What limits rendering in SXA Grid Placeholders

Tags: sxa, placeholders

We have an issue between our Prod and UAT environments when it comes to adding renderings from the Toolbox into the grid placeholders.

In our Prod environment, the placeholders that are generated by SXA grid seem to be limiting what rendering from the toolbox can be placed however I cannot seem to figure out what is telling these placeholders to limit the renderings

In our UAT environments there is no restriction

My question is where would this happen?

Using: Sitecore 9.0

Answer (score 1):

This is controlled by placeholder settings and available renderings in SXA. Your placeholder settings can set a list of allowed controls for a placeholder key. If there are no controls listed in the `Allowed Controls` field, then all controls are allowed in that placeholder:

[image]

If you are not serializing your placeholder settings between environments, then you could have a mismatch of the allowed controls between your UAT and Prod environments.

If your placeholder settings are ok, you may not be properly deploying your `Available Renderings` for your site. This section defines which renderings/controls are available on your site and which "group" they belong too:

[image]

If your components are not listed in any of the available rendering sections, you will not be able to add them to a placeholer.